# Does client need to open port 22 for sFTP

Tags: client, port, sftp

We have an sFTP server.

Our Vendor need to push (and pull) files  to/from this server.
Port 22  is open on our server.

Does the Vendor need to open port 22  OR can they use something like coreFTP without opening port 22  at their end (client)

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Aslong as they are able to make outbound connections only the server side will need port 22 open.